# mondrian - Count only unique members in sets

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I am new to Mondrian, and I need some help with MDX query.

For example:

```
year 1 id_client: 1,2
year 2 id_client: 2,3
year 3 id_client: 1
```

If I try to do a "distinct-count" aggregator for id_client, I get this result:

```
year 1  2
year 2  2
year 3  1
```

How can I calculate only new id_client? I need this result:

```
years  new
year 1  2   both clients are new
year 2  1   only client with ID = 3 is new
year 3  0   no new clients
```

Comment: 1. How is "new" defined? 2. However trivial could you please add an mdx script that you have attempted to solve this?

Comment: 1. Using `year` context. If I choose "year 1" and "year 2", I need to see `year 1 - 2 new, year 2 - 1 new` (because "client 2" is exists in "
year 1" ).  If I choose "year 1" and "year 3", I need to see `year 1 - 2 new, year 3 - 0 new`  (because "client 1" is exists in "
year 1" ).

Comment: 2. I try to use `distinct-count`.